How was the induced emf determined to be "equal" to the rate of change of flux?
Who determined, and how, the fact that the emf is exactly equal to the rate of change of flux, instead of only proportional?
At first this seems like a question of units, defining the magnetic flux in terms of the induced emf, but there are two equations that can be used to define the units of flux. These are the force on a length $\mathrm d\mathbf {s}$ of wire carrying current I:
$$\mathbf F \propto I\ \mathrm{d}\mathbf {s}\times \mathbf B$$
and the emf induced in a circuit by a varying magnetic flux (due to motion of the circuit or due to a changing magnetic field):
$$\text{emf} \propto \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\oint_{\text{loop}}\mathbf B \cdot \hat n \ \mathrm dS $$
If any one of these is used to fix the units for $B$ by setting the constant of proportionality (such as unity for SI units or $\frac{1}{c}$ for Gaussian units) then it remains to show that the other equation has the same constant of proportionality.
Nowadays it could be argued that the emf law (in the case of motion of the circuit) is the same as the force law (in the form of the Lorentz law) but not back in the day. The force on a current carrying wire was considered to be a force on the conductor itself, not on the charges inside it, and entirely separate from the electromotive forces which make currents flow.
How was this settled?

Maxwell cites Faraday and Felici.

Heaviside version if of interest too: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/what-is-heavisides-version-of-maxwells-equations

Concerning the question of "who determined the fact that the emf is exactly equal to the rate of change of flux, instead of only proportional?" , it might be Franz Ernst Neumann in 1845.
Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction

Right, but the question is also how. I can't read Neumann's original article as I don't speak German.
